# Is it possible to set the target of an anchor tag to a webview tag?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I want to open some links in my HTML in the background. I would like to open them in a hidden webview tag. I have tried to name the webview tag like so

```
<webview id="bgview" name="background-view" ></webview>
```

and then add a

```
<a href="some_link" target="background-view">
```

It doesn't work. Is there a simple way to accomplish this? Maybe a javascript function to wrap around the link? I also tried

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById(bgview).loadURL('some_link');">
```

Comment: there is no webview tah in HTML , you may you Object or iframe tag

Comment: I am using Electron and thus I have webview tags

Comment: My gut feeling is that you _may_ have to involve your main thread here. Since you initialise the renderer thread from there, you can setup a listener which can then communicate with your renderer thread and instruct it to drop a `<webview>` using the url that user just clicked on (if that's possible)

Comment: @customcommander Do you have an idea how to do that? I tried many options now and came to the same conclusion as you. I have not worked with the IPC so far. In the tutorials they just send messages. Wouldn't know how to send a webview to the html file.